# Firebase app throws me an error about not recognizing First Argument "email" in my signInWithEmailAndPassword method using vuejs

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I have an issue with my Vue.Js Firebase application cause eventually lets me sign up the user but then when I try to sign in the same already registered user throws me an error:

> signInWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string.

Both processes are almost equal except the signUp on one demands a confirmed password.

Is there something I'm missing?
Sign in process
HTML

```
<v-layout row>
  <v-flex xs12>
    <v-text-field
      name="email"
      label="Email"
      id="email"
      v-model="email"
      type="email"
      required
    ></v-text-field>
  </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

SCRIPT

```
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "signInPage",
  data() {
    return {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      name: ""
    };
  },
   methods: {
    ...mapActions(["signUserIn"]),
    signingIn() {
      this.$store.dispatch("signUserIn", {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
      });
    }
  },
```

VUEX Managment

```
ACTIONS:{
signUserIn({ commit }, payload) {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)

        .then((user) => {
          const newUser = {
            id: user.uid,
            registeredMeetsIds: [],
            fbKeys: {},
          };
          commit("clearSettingAuthUserError"); //ojo, esto se suponia iria despues del firebase
          commit("settingSignedInUser", newUser);
          console.log(payload.email);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          commit("settingAuthUserError", error);
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
}

MUTATIONS:{

settingSignedInUser(state, payload) {
      state.user = payload;
    },
}

STATE:{

user: null
}
```

Comment: If you add `console.log(payload.email)` right before calling `firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)`, what does it show?

Comment: says undefined i tried already

Comment: This means the problem isn't in the call to Firebase, but before that in the Vue code. I highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Once we rule out Firebase, your question essentially becomes "How do I pass the value of a Vue text field to my Actions?". Correctly scoping your question increases the chance that the right people will see it, and the folks without the correct knowledge (such as me) can spend their time helping other developers.